Confusing English Riddle
Riddle given by english teacher.
Answer is a one word "verb".
Hint not visible, yet constantly sown, In subtle nudges, it makes its presence known. Much like an anchor, it helps you moor, In the sea of memories, towards the familiar shore. A subtle essence with much behind, I am a concept and crucial to the mind, What am I? Can you unwind this bind? To find the answer, you must rewind.

Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange!

I think the verb is

remind


The most obvious hint to me was "In the sea of memories, towards the familiar shore."

